# Why does F# runtime throws a invalid program error when using struct decorated DU with big number of cases?

Tags: f#, runtime

I'm using a DU type as tags i.e. no trailing data, but at runtime, it throws an exception.

like

```
[<Struct>]
type Tag =
    | Case0
        :
    | CaseN
```

when N are getting big enough the runtime throws an exception.

> "System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an
> invalid program"

it goes away if I remove `[<Struct>]`, but the point of it is to eliminate deference and minimise byte size a pointer is 8 bytes and as a struct, it is 4 bytes instead.

I know I can use Enums instead but that causes an undesirable explicitly typing `Tag.Case0` instead of
`Case0` and the need to explicitly assign a number for each case are at best cumbersome.

I know that this is phrased as a general problem, but it is independent of the use in code.

Can anyone tell me why dotnet chose to only allow enum declaration with explicit values? I know us cases where it is needed, but in many cases, it is not important which value an enum case has as long each enum case has assigned a unique value.

Comment: What do you mean by "byte size a pointer is 8 bytes and as a struct, it is 4 bytes instead"? Pointers (aka references) are 64 bit on 64 bit systems, regardless of where they point to.

Comment: How big is N when it causes this error?

Comment: Have tested it on my computer N=50.

it is correct that a pointer is 64 bit on a 64 bit systems, if we look at the bare hardware. but a pointer can be represented in many ways. I don't know how exactly dotnet represent adresses, but it is not uncommon that all pointers is a power of 2 and how it is translated (if it be an offset from current adr, an offset from some base virtual adress or something different.

but if you use sizeof<Tag>, it return 8 for normal DU's and 4 for struct DU.
normal DU's are reference based and structs are inlined in memory given that there are no trailing data.

Comment: No [tag:compiler-construction] here. You are not constructing a compiler. Don't tag indiscrimately.

Answer (score 2):

This was a known bug in the compiler https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/5342 looks like it was fixed recently. I'd speculate the fix will be available when .NET 8 is released soon.